# replace new line with a space if next line starts with a word character

Tags: awk, unix-text-processing

I've large text file that looks like

```
some random : demo text for
illustration, can be long

and : some more

here is : another
one
```

I want an output like

```
some random : demo text for illustration, can be long
and : some more
here is : another one
```

I tried some strange, obviously faulty regex like `%s/\w*\n/  /g` but can't really get my head around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Using RS(record separator), setting it nullify. This is based on your shown samples only.

```
awk -v RS="" '{$1=$1} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another solution in case someone is looking for `printf` function with `awk`. Though 1st solution provided in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68236516/5866580) should be used IMHO, as an alternative adding these solutions too here.

***2nd solution:*** Adding solution to check if lines starts with alphabets, then only add them with previous lines or so.

```
awk '{printf("%s%s",$0~/^[a-zA-Z]/?(FNR>1 && prev~/^[a-zA-Z]/?OFS:""):ORS,$0);prev=$0} END{print ""}' Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** Note: This will work only if your lines has colon present in the lines as per shown samples.

```
awk '{printf("%s%s",$0~/:/?(FNR>1?ORS:""):OFS,$0)} END{print ""}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `printf` function of `awk`. Then using conditions, if current line has `:` and greater than 1 then print ORS else print nothing. If line doesn't contain `:` then print `OFS` for each line. In the `END` block of this program printing newline.